# Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key) in React app while initializing Firebase with API key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I am getting the following error in my React app when trying to initialize Firebase:

```
Uncaught FirebaseError: Firebase: Error (auth/invalid-api-key).
    at createErrorInternal (assert.ts:142:1)
    at _assert (assert.ts:167:1)
    at new Auth (auth.ts:56:1)
    at 

instance.INTERNAL.registerComponent._firebase_component__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.Component.setServiceProps.ActionCodeInfo.Operation.EMAIL_SIGNIN [as instanceFactory] (index.ts:82:1)

    at Provider.getOrInitializeService (provider.ts:318:1)
    at Provider.getImmediate (provider.ts:115:1)
    at FirebaseAppImpl._getService (firebaseApp.ts:138:1)
    at firebaseAppImpl.<computed> [as auth] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:185:1)
    at Object.serviceNamespace [as auth] (firebaseNamespaceCore.ts:166:1)
    at new Firebase (firebase.js:17:1)
```

I am using the following versions of React and Firebase:

- React: 18.2.0
- Firebase: 9.16.0

I have checked that the API key in my `.env` file is correct, but the error persists.

Here is the source code of my firebase.js file:

```
import app from "firebase/compat/app";
import "firebase/compat/auth";

const config = {
  apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN,
  databaseURL: process.env.REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL,
  projectId: process.env.REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.REACT_APP_ID,
};

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config);
    this.auth = app.auth();
  }

  // *** Auth API ***
  doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
    this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  doSignOut = () => this.auth.signOut();

  doPasswordReset = (email) => this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);

  doPasswordUpdate = (password) =>
    this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password);
}

export default Firebase;
```

.env file:

```
REACT_APP_API_KEY=AIzsdfceg7Cu22Ma8RYadHVnrSoRwQ-B7ZEejs
REACT_APP_AUTH_DOMAIN=devsproject-75523.firebaseapp.com
REACT_APP_DATABASE_URL = https://devsproject-75523-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/
REACT_APP_PROJECT_ID=devsproject-75523
REACT_APP_STORAGE_BUCKET=devsproject-75523.appspot.com
REACT_APP_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID=1009026371636
REACT_APP_ID=1:1009026371636:web:a57fr518532bc351d0f6f9
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I tried to do this on the config object:

```
const config {
        apiKey: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY || "mock_key",
        .....
}
```

now i am able to see the page instead of that empty view port, i don't know whether its a bandaid solution or does it actually solved anything:

Am i moving right, please i need your feedback

Comment: Have you tried `console.log(process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY)` before config? that's most likely to be undefined.

Comment: yes, its undefined. i don't know how this error even happened before I turned off my laptop everything was going smoothly. when I opened the project to complete the rest, I saw the above error. i even tried creating another project on firebase and replacing the keys and other data in .env still I am facing the same issue

Comment: .env file should be in the root folder of the project (NOT inside src folder but one level up. Remember, it should be at the same level as package.json) always remember to restart the local server when you have any change in the .env file.

Comment: What build system is your React app using? Is it `react-scripts` or something else (check your `package.json` _dependencies_ and _scripts_ sections)?

Comment: My issue has been resolved, it was because .env was inside the src instead of the root folder